# Override parent pom dependency

Tags: maven, selenium, dependencies

I made a simple EAR project with maven and wildfly, but I have some problems with obsolete dependencies.

Project structure is like:

```
Project
  --EarProject
  --BaseProject
  --WarProject
  --EjbProject
```

In parent Project's pom there is dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools</artifactId>
    <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

And in BaseProject's pom I use Selenium:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The problem is that in BaseProject Maven libraries I see older versions of Selenium (ie. selenium-firefox-driver 2.40.0 instead of newer 2.44.0) and because of bugs in 2.40.0 my app does not work corectly.
I tried to add:

```
<version>2.44.0</version>
```

in BaseProject's pom, but I got warning like

> Overriding managed version 2.40.0 for selenium-remote-driver

and it does not work.

How can I override version of dependency from parent's pom or exclude selenium from jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools dependency?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I override version of dependency from parent's pom

The "Overriding managed version 2.40.0 for selenium-remote-driver" warning  is a just a m2e warning *not* a Maven warning. With your code, you are correctly overriding the version of the dependency of the parent's pom. [See this bug at Eclipse site for m2e about this warning](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=346725). You can assert that by looking at the dependency tree (in Eclipse or with the [`mvn dependency:tree`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) command)

> or exclude selenium from jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools dependency?

You can do that with the [`exclusions`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) tag. It is a tag where you specify each groupId and artifactId that you want to exclude from the transitive dependencies resolved by Maven.